# How can I use bootstrap's popover with an additional condition?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

There is a simple example of popover [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9P64a/). How can I add a condition to this example? For example the popover should be triggered when it is hovered AND var "triggerPopover" is true.

HTML on jsfiddle:

```
<div class="container">

<a id="popoverData" class="btn" href="#" data-content="Popover with data-trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title" data-trigger="hover">Popover with data-trigger</a>

<a id="popoverOption" class="btn" href="#" data-content="Popup with option trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title">Popup with option trigger</a>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $('#popoverData').popover();
 $('#popoverOption').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
```